# Unable to boot QNX 6.5.0 on Beaglebone black board

Tags: beagleboneblack, beagleboard, qnx, qnx-neutrino, qnx-ifs

My Beaglebone Black work fine under the prebuilt image the **images/prebuilt-bsp-ti-beaglebone.ifs** comes with QNX **bsp-nto650-ti-beaglebone-sp1-trunk-201209071340.zip** which downloaded from foundry27.

When I copy my newly built image on SD card and try to boot on beaglebone black board it fails with below error. Actually I cut the following image form "http://www.openqnx.com/phpbbforum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15755" which I compared the logs and comfirm they are absolutely same to mine.

[image: logs]

I haven't tested the higher version 6.6.0 yet as it can't complie successfully under QNX Momentics 6.5.0.

Sincerely hope anyone to help me to understand what's going wrong here and how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found where this problem came from: the Beaglebone Black BSP must be complied under SDP 6.5.0 SP1, I had installed SDP 6.5.0 but not the SP1 yet. The size of the image complied under SDP 6.5.0 SP1 QDE is 8.4M same as the size of prebuilt one, as the size of unable-boot one is 7.*M.

I haven't test it because my Beaglebone Black was dead and I sent it to the original factory for repairing. I'll tell the real effect after I tested it.